# Junit testing with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, rest, junit, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing a Junit test with apache httpclient. The testCreate method successfully insert a record to the database but the status return is 500 which make the test case to fail.

Below is the test case,

```
public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/mediaactivity/videoAssignment";

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("xAuthorization", "123");
        request.addHeader("correlationId", "123");

        String json = "{"+
                "\"VideoType\": \"Sample\","+
                "\"groupType\": \"INDIVIDUAL\","+
                "\"submissionMethod\": \"test\","+
                "\"title\": \"test me\""+
                "}";

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
        request.setEntity(entity);
        // When
        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);
        // Then
        assertThat(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED));
    }
```

The controller looks like,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/videoAssignment", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public HttpEntity<VideoAssignment> createVideoAssingnment(
  //@ApiParam are there..){

    //other methods
    return new ResponseEntity<>(va, HttpStatus.CREATED);
 }
```

what i am missing here?

Comment: Status 500 is definitely caused at the server end. You should check the server logs for any errors.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the controller, as it may be that there is an error before the return statement. You can also try to catch any throwable and see if it gets triggered.

Comment: actually no error before the return statement because i debug and check till the last line

Comment: @jozzy I use spring boot and my log4j log level is DEBUG. But it does not show any server error in the log

Comment: You can write a filter/interceptor to log responses form your webserver and check